# Question about "min" in minmax theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the proof of the minmax theorem on wiki. If $U$ is a $k-$ dimensional subspace, $\lambda_k\leq\text{max}\{R_A(x):x\in U\}$ where $R_A$ is the Rayleigh–Ritz quotient and $\lambda_k$ is a real eigenvalue of the Hermitian operator $A$. Since this holds for all subspaces $U$ with dim$(U)=k$, it follows that $\lambda_k\leq\text{min}_{\text{dim}U=k}\text{max}_{(x\neq 0)\in U}\{R_A(x)\}$.

My question is, why is this last part a min, instead of an inf? We can have infinitely many subspaces of dimension $k$, and I don't see immediately why we can say there is a minimum for this set.

Comment: At this point, you might not know that this is actually a min and not an inf but since the theorem states that you should have an equality, once you show the other direction, you'll know that this is actually a min and the inf is attained.

Comment: You can build the subspace where the infimum is achieved out of the eigenvectors